# Link in the comments is rendered with semicolon

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, markdown, markdown-rendering

I've got the following URI:

```
https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'
```

In the post Markdown, it would be rendered as https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl' which doesn't work - you have to use

```
[https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl')
```

instead which becomes the expected https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'. OK, standard delimiter parsing, whatever.

Now I'm putting the exact same two snippets in a comment, and - guess what - they're rendered differently than in a post. Not a big deal in general, we know that, but what freaks me out is that the plain link is getting followed by a semicolon that can be found nowhere in the source!

```
Demo: https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl' [https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl')
```

below renders as

> Demo: https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'; https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'

Where does this "**;**" come from? Can you make it go away, please?

Comment: Demo: https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl' [https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl')

Comment: Interestingly, the preview is also broken. Click edit, and the 'Demo' is quite a bit different from what's shown here

Comment: Looks like it's something left over from the database query retrieving the post... I'd report this using the Contact Us form ASAP as a security vulnerability if I were you.

Comment: @cybermonkey nah, that won't be from the database; pretty sure that's just cshtml, and the subtleties of when a trailing `;` is / isn't needed (mini-markdown doesn't even touch the DB)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the magic hyperlinks as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83837/strange-character-replacement-on-so)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but [meta-tag:status-bydesign], really?