# Strange things happening to code in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

I've noticed strange things happening to code in comments lately

Wrote the following comment

```
`"XS1".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"‌​))`
```

After adding the comment, this appeared however:

`"XS1".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"‌​;))`

Just for fun I added a backslash before the `"`, i.e.

```
`"XS1".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII\"‌​))`
```

but this resulted in

`"XS1".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII\&quo‌​t;‌​))`

Also I observed code at the end of the link text breaking the link markup.

I checked the page containing the comment in Firefox and Chrome and both rendered the result the same...

What is happening there?

I noticed it here: [Part of a string not getting inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993351/part-of-a-string-not-getting-inserted#comment-65352911) (not the exact code comment text, but I tested and deleted some versions of this comment, including the ones mentioned above.)

Comment: can you provide a link please?

Comment: `"XS1".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"‌​))`

Comment: @Sklivvz http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332658/strange-things-happening-to-code-in-comments#comment384622_332658

Comment: @Sklivvz added a link to the question. Not exactly the text in the question, but I've tested these comment texts below that comment, but deleted those comments afterwards, since they weren't adding anything of value...

Comment: I see you're using Java. `"You_should_totally_drop_that_and_use_jQuery""`

Comment: ^-- It seems to only be triggered for strings over a certain length containing no whitespace and at least three double quotes.

Comment: reproed, i'll take a look soonish, like tomorrow

Comment: It seems to only happen at specific offsets or something though. `\"` many times: `\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"`

Comment: @Sklivvz what happened to my 6-8 random units of time!?!

Comment: Can someone add a screenshot of the bug for those future visitors from the land where this is fixed?

Comment: @Braiam 6-8 sevenths of a day ;)

Comment: I've encountered an issue where SO adds invisible characters to comments - for example, in this comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89572/make-a-somewhat-self-referential-string/89587#comment218515_89587 invisible characters are added after g in length or after c in slice. The characters added are also strange - \u200c and \u200b

Comment: probably related: [Link in the comments is rendered with semicolon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326484/1048572)

Comment: straaaange things... (*If you had a Disney childhood you'd get the pun*)

Comment: @eithedog I've noticed that when copying code from comments and sometimes answers but never really thought anything of it

Comment: The same thing happens in Google Translate, if you type in `&#8230;` which is values `...`, google translate replaces `&#8230;`  with `...`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fixed.

Here's the thing. We insert an invisible, optional non-breaking character after 60 uninterrupted characters, every 20. This is to allow comments to wrap when you do shenanigans like write `VERYLONGSEQUENCESOFCHARACTERSWITHOUTANYSPACEJUSTBECAUSEYOUCAN`.

The algorithm did not take into account html entities, and in this case it put this character in the middle of `&quot;`.

Now the algorithm is aware of them. Next step: invoke Cthulhu.

Comment: Or Zalgo, if you're using regexes.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use `word-wrap: break-word;`? This would only break words when necessary - in fact, `.post-text, .wmd-preview` even use it to prevent the exact same issue inside post contents. Inserting spaces just seems absurdly hackish, especially since longer character will still break it, eg. WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol sure, as soon as we get out of having a table-based layout with variable width, we'll use `break-word`. If you investigate a tad deeper (including javascript) you'll know what I mean...

Comment: @Sklivvz The solution to that, from an answer given right here on SO, is to use lable-layout:fixed.

Comment: @MrLister Although that ends up causing issues with the vote/flag columns no longer being wide enough because they rely on "bad" table behaviour... Seems like a rewrite is needed there!

Comment: Is this [overflow](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ALbag.png), by-design and as expected? (Oh and grats on getting to 20k, you now have those privileges which you always had ;)..)

Comment: @BhargavRao it's as expected, we can't fix all the breakages without fixing the HTML first.